# F# printf string

Tags: string, f#, printf

Im puzzled

```
let test = "aString"

let callMe =
    printfn test
```

Why isn't this working? Throws below error at compile time:

> The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>'

This works fine:

```
printfn "aString"
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

That's because the `format` parameter is not actually a `string`. It's `TextWriterFormat<'T>` and the F# compiler converts the string format into that type. But it doesn't work on `string` variables, because the compiler can't convert the `string` to `TextWriterFormat<'T>` at runtime.

If you want to print the content of the variable, you shouldn't even try to use `printfn` this way, because the variable could contain format specifications.

You can either use the `%s` format:

```
printfn "%s" test
```

Or use the .Net `Console.WriteLine()`:

```
Console.WriteLine test
```

Don't forget to add `open System` at the top of the file if you want to use the `Console` class.

Comment: I would add that using `Console.WriteLine` in F# code is not idiomatic, and the `printf` version is much more common.

Comment: Ah ok makes sense if the compiler converts it i guess.
Ended up with printfn "%s" test

Comment: you can also do `stdout.WriteLine test` where I guess the only advantage is that it is one char shorter and you don't need to open `System`

Comment: Makes me wonder why there isn't just a *print* function that does no formatting. I guess it would be easy to define.

let print value = printfn "%s" value

Answer (score 4):

In line with what [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) said, you might also try this:

```
let test = "aString"
let callMe = printfn (Printf.TextWriterFormat<_> test)
callMe
```

Comment: Nope; value restriction.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answers below.
You may also write like this:

```
let test = "aString"
let print =
   printfn $"{test}"
```

Comment: That substitutes `test` as a string variable, as indicated, and produces `aString`, but it doesn't allow for format specifiers in `test`. Change to `let test = " aString %s"` and it produces ` aString %s`.