# F#: Why doesn't this code compile?

Tags: f#

This compiles and executes as expected.

```
printfn "value=%i" 1
```

It prints `value=1` to the console.

But this doesn't even compile:

```
let format = "value=%i"
printfn format 1
```

I get the following compilation error: **The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'Printf.TextWriterFormat<('a -> 'b)>'**

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

This is a duplicate of [F# printf string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440204/f-printf-string). I'm closing this post. Thanks

Comment: There is a lot of magic with format strings.  You need to set the type of format to match the error message.

Comment: Try this: `printfn (Printf.TextWriterFormat<_> format) 1`.